# Emacs command for searching in files

Tags: emacs

I want to search in all files from the current folder for macro *CODE_INIT_PARAMETERS*.

I can do <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>occur</kbd>, <kbd>Return</kbd> CODE_INIT_PARAMETERS <kbd>Return</kbd>, but this shows only entries from open buffers.

Is there a way to search all files from current folder, from Emacs, without switching to M-x shell and then [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep)? I want to avoid grep, because for some commands (M-x occur) Emacs do jumps to offending code, and I want that too.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You can try `M-x rgrep`.

It will ask for:

- the directory where you want to search recursively
- a file pattern for the files you want to include in the search
- the pattern you want to search

As an extra, it will exclude source control private directories from your search (like CVS, .svn or .git).

Comment: You need grep and find (from GnuWin32), and GNU find must be before Windows find.exe in the PATH. grep and find are installed with EmacsW32.

Comment: I'd also add that the `rgrep` broken a few. I.e. when I entered a pattern for a files, it found nothing. After some struggle I figured out the reason: it doesn't knows what the dots means. I.e. i wanted to search a pattern in .h, .c, .cpp files, instead of my pattern `.*\.[ch].*` I should have been entered `*\.[ch]*`.

Answer (score 14):

Emacs provides a built-in command:

```
M-x grep RET CODE_INIT_PARAMETERS *.c
```

(and `'grep-find` to search sub directories)

Though I prefer the interface provided by an external package [`igrep`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/igrep.el) (which provides the commands `igrep` and `igrep-find`).

Comment: M-x grep-find will also allow you to iterate through the results, the same way as occur.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to do something like this?

    M-x grep "CODE_INIT_PARAMETERS" *.c

It's worth mentioning that using a prefix argument will automatically set the search up to seek what the cursor is over and for the kind of file you're in.

    C-U M-x grep

Comment: @justinhj, so correct.  My lack of using `M-x grep` shows through.

Comment: Thanks, I quite new to emacs, and didn't know about M-x grep and igrep.el  They do my job just perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

If you open a folder in dired, and mark all of the files (with 'm') you can run 'dired-do-search ('A' in my bindings). This will search all marked files. To get to the next one, run tags-loop-continue (M-,)

I have set up several ELisp functions to mark various subsets of the files (.h files, .cpp files, etc.) and to create a recursive dired to search a whole tree...

Comment: I must do something for my bindings. It works but it's not handy for the moment. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This is an improvement on Trey Jackson's suggestion.

M-x grep

You will see the grep command, e.g. `grep -nH -e`

Add R to the first set of flags (for recursive), and put your search term after -e

```
grep -nHR -e CODE_INIT_PARAMETERS
```

Hit RET. The results will be understandable by Emacs -- you will be able to click or otherwise navigate to them, like M-x occur. You may need to put the search directory at the end of the command:

```
grep -nHR -e CODE_INIT_PARAMETERS /path/to/root/of/search
```

Comment: Yah, that's why I like `'igrep`, the interface is much more intuitive.

Answer (score 6):

M-x find-grep-dired also works similarly as rgrep

Answer (score 2):

In cases where

1. you may be searching repeatedly; **and**
2. etags *will* work

you might consider using [`etags`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/etags/) and invoking either `find-tag` (bound to `M-.` by default) or `tags-search` (no default binding but can be continued with `M-,`).

Answer (score 1):

There is as well [ack-grep mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-pt/FullAck) for Emacs which uses the [ack-grep](http://betterthangrep.com/) tool which is specifically designed for ''grepping'' programming languages and IMHO looks nicer than the output of M-x grep.

But as mentioned earlier etags should be the proper way!

Comment: [RipGrep performs significantly faster than Ack and Ag.. and pt and git grep and ....](https://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/)